# Sequelize.js: how to use migrations and sync

Tags: database, node.js, database-migration, sequelize.js

I'm close to having my project ready to launch. I have big plans for after launch and the database structure is going to change -- new columns in existing tables as well as new tables, and new associations to existing and new models.

I haven't touched migrations in Sequelize yet, since I've only had testing data which I don't mind wiping out every time the database changes.

To that end, at present I'm running `sync force: true` when my app starts up, if I have changed the model definitions. This deletes all the tables and makes them from scratch. I could omit the `force` option to have it only create new tables. But if existing ones have changed this is not useful.

So once I add in migrations how do things work? Obviously I don't want existing tables (with data in them) to be wiped out, so `sync force: true` is out of the question. On other apps I've helped develop (Laravel and other frameworks) as part of the app's deployment procedure we run the migrate command to run any pending migrations. But in these apps the very first migration has a skeleton database, with the database in the state where it was some time early in development -- the first alpha release or whatever. So even an instance of the app late to the party can get up to speed in one go, by running all migrations in sequence.

How do I generate such a "first migration" in Sequelize? If I don't have one, a new instance of the app some way down the line will either have no skeleton database to run the migrations on, or it will run sync at the start and will make the database in the new state with all the new tables etc, but then when it tries to run the migrations they won't make sense, since they were written with the original database and each successive iteration in mind.

My thought process: at every stage, the initial database plus each migration in sequence should equal (plus or minus data) the database generated when `sync force: true` is run. This is because the model descriptions in the code describe the database structure. So maybe if there is no migration table we just run sync and mark all the migrations as done, even though they weren't run. Is this what I need to do (how?), or is Sequelize supposed to do this itself, or am I barking up the wrong tree? And if I'm in the right area, surely there should be a nice way to auto generate most of a migration, given the old models (by commit hash? or even could each migration be tied to a commit? I concede I am thinking in a non-portable git-centric universe) and the new models. It can diff the structure and generate the commands needed to transform the database from old to new, and back, and then the developer can go in and make any necessary tweaks (deleting/transitioning particular data etc).

When I run the sequelize binary with the `--init` command it gives me an empty migrations directory. When I then run `sequelize --migrate` it makes me a SequelizeMeta table with nothing in it, no other tables. Obviously not, because that binary doesn't know how to bootstrap my app and load the models.

I must be missing something.

TLDR: how do I set up my app and its migrations so various instances of the live app can be brought up to date, as well as a brand new app with no legacy starting database?

Comment: I've answered pertaining to your workflow, but Ideally all Tables should be setup using Migrations. Even if you're using `sync` for now, the idea is that migrations "generate" the entire database, so relying on a skeleton is in itself a problem. Ruby on Rails workflow, for instance, uses Migrations for everything, and it's pretty awesome once you get used to it.  
Edit: And yes, I noticed this question is pretty old, but seeing as there has never been a satisfactory answer and people may come here looking for guidance, I figured I should contribute.

Answer (score 104):

### Generating the "first migration"

In your case, the most reliable way is to do it almost manually. I would suggest to use [sequelize-cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) tool. The syntax is rather plain:

```
sequelize init
...
sequelize model:create --name User --attributes first_name:string,last_name:string,bio:text
```

This will create both model AND migration. Then, manually merge your existing models with generated with sequelize-cli, and do the same with migrations. After doing this, wipe database (if possible), and run

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

This will create schema with migrations. You should do this only once to switch to proper process of schema developments (without sync:force, but with authoritative migrations).

Later, when you need to change schema:

1. Create a migration: `sequelize migration:create`
2. Write up and down functions in your migration file
3. According to your changes in migration file, change your model manually
4. Run `sequelize db:migrate`

### Running migrations on production

Obviously you can't ssh to production server and run migrations by hands. Use [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug), framework agnostic migration tool for Node.JS to perform pending migrations before app starts.

You can get a list of pending/not yet executed migrations like this:

```
umzug.pending().then(function (migrations) {
  // "migrations" will be an Array with the names of
  // pending migrations.
});
```

Then execute migrations (**inside callback**). The execute method is a general purpose function that runs for every specified migrations the respective function:

```
umzug.execute({
  migrations: ['some-id', 'some-other-id'],
  method: 'up'
}).then(function (migrations) {
  // "migrations" will be an Array of all executed/reverted migrations.
});
```

And my suggestion is to do it before app starts and tries to serve routes every time. Something like this:

```
umzug.pending().then(function(migrations) {
    // "migrations" will be an Array with the names of
    // pending migrations.
    umzug.execute({
        migrations: migrations,
        method: 'up'
    }).then(function(migrations) {
        // "migrations" will be an Array of all executed/reverted migrations.
        // start the server
        app.listen(3000);
        // do your stuff
    });
});
```

I can't try this right now, but at first look it should work.

#### UPD Apr. 2016

After a year, still useful, so sharing my current tips. For now, I'm installing `sequelize-cli` package as required **live** dependency, and then modify NPM startup scripts in `package.json` like this:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "grunt && sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all && node bin/www",
  "start": "sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all && node bin/www"
},
...
```

The only thing I need to do on production server is `npm start`. This command will run all migrations, apply all seeders and start app server. No need to call umzug manually.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for. It doesn't seem as magic and automatic as it "should" be, but maybe this is the best that can be hoped for. However, I'm currently not working with Sequelize and won't be able to test this any time soon. But if anyone else agrees that this solution is good, I'll accept this answer. I still find it a little sad that there appears to be no way to automatically make these migrations from the diffs between model versions.

Comment: @tremby the only framework I've used that really **understands** models was Django. It analyses models and asks like "Well, it seems you renamed field name to first_name in model User. Would you like to create migration for it?" In Django it works almost magically, other tools I've used assume the same migrations approach I've mentioned above: you are responsible for writing migrations yourself, deeply understanding what field of what type to add to be actual to your current model states

Comment: You can get rid of `pending` and then `execute` and just do `umzug.up().then(function (migrations) { app.listen(3000); })`. According to the umzug documentation, this will execute all pending migrations.

Comment: When you complete the migration, is it common to add the fields to the schema in the original model file?

Comment: @f1nn I have a question about your set up, how do you handle app clustering and availability? I will integrate pm2 in my workflow and maybe it doesn't work straightforward with the npm scripts.

Comment: @f1nn I ended up executing `./node_modules/sequelize-cli/bin/sequelize db:migrate` just before setting the routes with node module `child_process.exec()` method, that way `umzug` is hidden to the application and it is contained in `app.js` which makes it work with `pm2 start app.js`.

Comment: I have the same concern as @diosney but our app is running on heroku. There is no way for me to control the concurrency of the restarts so umzug might be running in several instances at the same time.
I wonder if umzug uses a lock on the database. I mean I'm sure it uses a transaction of some kind, but I wonder if this transaction prevents race conditions in this regard.

Comment: @Floby I ended up disabling automatic migrations on staging and production, since if they ran on multiple threads, the database gets corrupted every single time due migrations running in parallel :(

Comment: @diosney bummer :(

Comment: @diosney that's probably because you're not returning Promises from your migrations (and/or you're not awaiting Promises returned by queryInterface methods within a single migration)

Answer (score 18):

Just learning this myself, but I think I would recommend using migrations now so you get used to them. I've found the best thing for figuring out what goes in the migration is to look at the sql on the tables created by `sequelize.sync()` and then build the migrations from there.

```
migrations -c [migration name]
```

Will create the template migration file in a migrations directory. You can then populate it with the fields you need created. This file will need to include `createdAt`/`updatedAt`, fields needed for associations, etc.

**For initial table creation down should have:**

```
migration.dropTable('MyTable');
```

But subsequent updates to the table structure can leave this out and just use alter table.

```
./node_modules/.bin/sequelize --migrate
```

**An example create would look like:**

```
module.exports = {
  up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.createTable(
        'MyTable',
        {
          id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
          },
          bigString: {type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false},
          MyOtherTableId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
          },
          updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
          }
        });
    done();
  },
  down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.dropTable('MyTable');
    done();
  }
```

**To redo from start:**

```
./node_modules/.bin/sequelize --migrate --undo
./node_modules/.bin/sequelize --migrate
```

**I'm using coffee to run a seed file to populate the tables after:**

```
coffee server/seed.coffee
```

**This just has a create function in it that looks something like:**

```
user = db.User.create
  username: 'bob'
  password: 'suruncle'
  email: 'bob@bob.com'
.success (user) ->
  console.log 'added user'
  user_id = user.id
  myTable = [
    field1: 'womp'
    field2: 'rat'

    subModel: [
      field1: 'womp'
     ,
      field1: 'rat'
    ]
  ]
```

Remember to take your `sync()` out of index in your models or it will overwrite what the migrations and seed do.

Docs are at http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/migrations/ of course. But the basic answer is you have to add everything in yourself to specify the fields you need. It doesn't do it for you.

Comment: I wasn't asking how to create and run migrations -- as you pointed out, that's all available in the documentation. What I was asking is how to use them in the context of a reusable application where existing instances need to be updated to a newer database version and new instances need that database made from scratch. Or perhaps you *are* answering that, and saying that I shouldn't be using sync() at all, and making the initial database and all changes to it in migrations. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @tremby I think that is what he's saying.  You can either use sync and deal with the results, or you can create the migrations all manually.  Our frameworks, in Rails-esque fashion, generate migration files based on a schema diff, I would LOVE if Sequelize would do that for me.  Too much of a pain to make migrations manually...

Comment: It's a shame that you can't `sequelize.sync()` then have a generated script that creates all of the base tables and indices as your first migration (similar to rails' `schema.rb`.)  After reading through this, it seems your best bet might be to export your initial schema as sql, then put it into a big `exec` statement in your very first migration.  Then from there you're running incremental changes against a known "version 1.0" starting point.

Answer (score 15):

For *development*, there is now an option to sync the current tables by altering their structure. Using the latest version from the [sequelize github repo](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/7230), you can now run sync with the `alter` parameter.

```
Table.sync({alter: true})
```

A caveat from the docs:

> Alters tables to fit models. Not recommended for production use. Deletes data in columns that were removed or had their type changed in the model.

Answer (score 10):

I went through this post and similar questions, it didn't really answer it for me. Migrations are useful for spinning up local databases and for updating data in production

I asked the question here and answered it as well: [Workflow for handling sequelize migrations and initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003107/workflow-for-handling-sequelize-migrations-and-initialization)

TL-DR version for a greenfield project

1. Design your database schema as you traditionally would using pure SQL scripts or if you use a gui tool instead
2. When you finalize all your 95% of your db schema and your happy with it, go ahead and move it to sequelize by moving the entire `.sql` file over
3. Make your first migration. Run `sequelize init:migrate` in the whatever folder where your `models` are at
4. Make your first migrations file. Run `sequelize migration:generate --name [name_of_your_migration]`
5. In that migration file, put this code in there

```
("use strict");
/**
 * DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE; CREATE SCHEMA public
 * ^ there's a schema file with all the tables in there. it drops all of that, recreates
 */
const fs = require("fs");
const initialSqlScript = fs.readFileSync("./migrations/sql/Production001.sql", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});
const db = require("../models");
module.exports = {
  up: () => db.sequelize.query(initialSqlScript),
  down: () =>
    db.sequelize.query(`DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE; CREATE SCHEMA public;
`),
};
```

[image]

with this general folder structure

[image]

1. Now your sequelize setup is synced with your initial database schema
2. when you want to edit your database schema, run this again `sequelize migration:generate --name [name_of_your_migration]`
3. Go ahead and make your modifications here on the `up` and `down` migration paths. These are your ALTER statements to change column names, DELETE, ADD columns etc
4. Run `sequelize db:migrate`
5. You want the models synced to the changes to your remote db, so what you can do now is `npm install sequelize-auto`.
6. This will read the the current database schema on your database and auto generate model files. Use a command similar to this `sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d sequelize_auto_test -h localhost -u my_username -p 5432 -x my_password -e postgres` found under https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto

You can use git to see difflogs on your model, there should be only changes reflecting changes in the database model. As a side note, do not ever modify the `models` directly if you use `sequelize auto`, as this will generate them for you. Likewise, you no longer should modify your database schema directly with SQL files, granted this is an option as you can import those `.sql` files as well

Now your database schema is up to date, and you've officially moved over to sequelize database migrations only.

Everything is version controlled. This is the ideal workflow for database and backend developer

Answer (score 3):

Now with the new sequelize migration is very simple.

This is a example what you can do.

```
    'use strict';

    var Promise = require('bluebird'),
        fs = require('fs');

    module.exports = {
        up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {

            return Promise
                .resolve()
                .then(function() {
                    return fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../initial-db.sql', 'utf-8');
                })
                .then(function (initialSchema) {
                    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(initialSchema);
                })
        },

        down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
            return Promise
                .resolve()
                .then(function() {
                    return fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../drop-initial-db.sql', 'utf-8');
                })
                .then(function (dropSql) {
                    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(dropSql);
                });
        }
    };
```

Remember you have to set:

`"dialectOptions": { "multipleStatements": true }`

on database config.

Comment: Doesn't this just drop and re-create the database?

Comment: I think that using an initial large sql file is not the recommended way to do it, since it will tie up the adapter and database, which otherwise will be database agnostic ,since you can use for development sqlite and for production mariadb or other.

Answer (score 2):

Use version.
Version of the application depends on the version of the database.
If the new version requires an update of a database, create migration for it.

update: I decided to abandon the migration ([KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) and run script update_db (sync forse: false) when it is needed.

Comment: Similar to my response to user1916988's answer, are you saying I shouldn't be using `sync()` at all, and that I need to manually write the migrations from the schema of the older version's models to the newer version's models?

Comment: I +1 ed because of your update. Im actually thinking of doing the same. Writing all migrations manually when the app can do that is a bit stupid, so im gonna just make a manual script that runs the app once and runs the sync function.

Answer (score 2):

Sequelize can run arbitrary SQL **asynchronously**.

What I would do is:

- Generate a Migration (To use as first migration);
- Dump your database, something like: `mysql_dump -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME > FILE.SQL`
- Either paste the full dump as text (Dangerous) or load a File with the full dump in Node:

  - `var baseSQL = "LOTS OF SQL and it's EVIL because you gotta put \
    backslashes before line breakes and \"quotes\" and/or sum" + 
    " one string for each line, or everything will break";`
  - `var baseSQL = fs.readFileSync('../seed/baseDump.sql');`
- Run this dump on Sequelize Migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (migration, DataTypes) {
    var baseSQL = "whatever" // I recommend loading a file
    migration.migrator.sequelize.query(baseSQL);
  }
}
```

That should take care of setting up the database, albeit the async thing may become a problem. If that happens, I'd look at a way to defer returning the `up` sequelize function until the async `query` function is finished.

More about mysql_dump: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html
More about Sequelize Migrations: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/migrations/
More about Running SQL from within Sequelize Migration: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/313

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, and after reading the documentation, you don't need to have that first migration that you are talking about. All you have to do is to call `sync` in order to create the tables.

`sequelize.sync()`

You can also run a simple model synchronization by doing something like:

`Project.sync()` but I think that `sequelize.sync()` is a more useful general case for your project (as long as you import the good models at start time).

(taken from http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/models#database-synchronization)

This will create all **initial** structures. Afterwards, you will only have to create migrations in order to evolve your schemas.

hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think you read the original post very thoroughly, or perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I'm more than aware of `sequelize.sync()` and what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my current workflow.  I'm open to suggestions.

1. Set sequelize to create tables that don't exist
2. Set sequelize
   to drop and re-create all tables in a blank database called
   _blank
3. Use a mysql tool to compare
   _blank and  and sync changes using
   that tool.  Still looking for an affordable tool that can do this on
   mac.  MySql workbench looks like you can import a model from an
   existing schema, and then sync schema.  Trying to figure out how to
   do this via command line to make it easy.

That way you don't have to manually update the migrations table and have to worry about fat fingers, but you still get an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Friend I had the same question and managed to understand how to use them.

I started without ORM sequelize therefore I already had a data model.
I had to generate the models automatically with sequelize-auto and generate their migrations with this file that you create https://gist.github.com/ahelord/a7a7d293695b71aadf04157f0f7dee64 and put in sync (`{Force: false}`)
This is in dev.I would have to version the model and the migrations and execute them every time I pull the code.

In production the server is only upstairs so you only have to run migrations and in each commit manage as you will version the model without stopping the backend

Answer (score 0):

There is even more simple way (avoiding Sequalize). Which goes like this:

1. You type a command inside your project: **npm run migrate:new**
2. This creates 3 files. A js file, and two sql files named up and down
3. You put your SQL statement in those files, which is pure sql
4. Then you type: **npm run migrate:up** or **npm run migrate:down**

For this to work, please have a look at the [db-migrate](https://github.com/db-migrate/node-db-migrate) module.

Once you get it setup (which is not difficult), changing your DB is really easy and saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run a migration right after the `db.sync`. This is because I'm running integration tests with Jest and wanted to pre-populate the DB with the seeds I had, during the `globalSetup` phase.

Then, I resolved it with `execSync`:

```js
const { db } = require('./db'); 
const { execSync } = require("child_process"); 

module.exports = async (globalConfig, projectConfig) => {
  await db.authenticate()  
  await db.sync({ force: true });
  execSync(`sequelize-cli db:migrate`, {stdio: 'inherit'}) // migrate
  execSync(`sequelize-cli db:seed:all`, {stdio: 'inherit'}) // seed
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the example what should be had in our migration file using Sequelize.
We have 3 files here which are consist of Category,Mem,and addColumn/skeleton.js
1.

```
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  description: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  }
});
```

2. id: {
   allowNull: false,
   autoIncrement: true,
   primaryKey: true,
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER
   },
   author: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
   },
   title: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
   },
   imageURL: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
   },
   votes: {
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER
   },
   isFunny: {
   type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
   },
   createdAt: {
   allowNull: false,
   type: Sequelize.DATE
   },
   updatedAt: {
   allowNull: false,
   type: Sequelize.DATE
   }
   });
3. 

```
await queryInterface.addColumn('Memes', 'CategoryId', {
  type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
  references:{
    model: 'Categories',
    key: 'id'
  },
  onUpdate: 'cascade',
  onDelete: 'cascade'
} )
```

},

async down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {

```
await queryInterface.removeColumn('Memes', 'CategoryId', {})
```