# Nodejs / PostgreSQL sequelize - How to update /change a model in the database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I created a model using sequelize (the code is below) but dont understand how I can update the model. When I changed the model, the old one (with name,num_stars and amenities) still appears in my db and I thought as long i use - sync() - I do update model changes, but apparently not. Can anyone help? Thank you!

my postgreSQL model: db/index.js:

```
var db = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/ajax', {
 logging: false
});

var Hotel = db.define('hotel', {

    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    num_stars: {
     type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
     validate: { min: 1, max: 5 }
   },
    amenities: Sequelize.STRING
})

module.exports=Hotel;
```

part of server.js

```
app.listen(1337, function () {
    db.sync()
    .then(function(){
        console.log('Server listening!');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not about to answer because migrations are very application specific, but this is the entire reason for Sequelize's Migrations (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/). You write code defining how the new scheme relates to the old one, and Sequelize runs all your data through it ensuring it's processed according to your rules.

Answer (score 0):

In Sequelize.js, updating a model falls under the migration progress and the only way I know how to do it is via the Sequelize CLI (npm install -g seqelize-cli).  [This previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105748/sequelize-js-how-to-use-migrations-and-sync/29941038#29941038) should give you all the answers you need!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that all I had to do was to add - sync: true -

```
var db = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/ajax', {
logging: false,
sync: true 
});
```