# Workflow for handling sequelize migrations and initialization?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I don’t get how sequelize migrations workflow works. I have a greenfield project, the database is designed using SQL scripts. We used `sequelize auto` to generate the models thereafter.

I need to now generate a migrations file starting out, so I can run the CLI to run SQL queries to create new tables with columns etc for locally provisioned databases.

There’s no 3rd party tools afaik to convert the SQL script I have into a Sequelize migrations file. I have to do this manually for 60 tables. There is a script method of auto-creating it, but it uses a seperate format that doesn’t have backward compatability for undoing migrations (sequelize-auto-migrations).

When I update the sequelize model schema in my file, there’s not a one off way command to have migrations file synchronize to those changes, via a diffing mechanisms based off the last migration execution ran.

This means I have to modify the model, AND modify the migrations file, leading to potential human error and duplicate redundant work.

so my issues are

1. does sequelize have a way to initialize the first migrations file?
2. is there a tool I can use when I modify models in sequelize, and generate the new migrations file automatically based off some diffing mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

okay I found out

For step 1, you can run a `queryInterface.sequelize.query(<query>)` and take the SQL scripts / run them right in sequelize for initialization. https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html. This short code references the sql script as the first migration

[image]

For step 2, you can modify the file and update the migrations manually, and run `sequelize-auto` to pull the latest changes from the remote/local db